# Не удается получить доступ к сайту visual studio code

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

пытаюсь запустить проект(сайт) без отладки в Visual Studio Code, в итоге вижу надпись в браузере "Не удается получить доступ к сайту", хотя до этого проект запускался очень хорошо в браузере. Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что у вас за сервер используется, как он настроен? на чем написан сайт, какие конфиги vs code (launch.json)?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, а где эту информацию посмотреть можно в проекте ?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, относительно launch.json - картинка в вопросе, отредактированная

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, сайт написан на HTML 5, CSS3, JS